# Data member of reference type provides "loophole" around const-correctness

Tags: c++, class, reference, constants

I've recently stumbled onto the following "loophole" around const-correctness:

```
struct Inner {
  int field = 0;
  void Modify() {
    field++;
  }
};

struct Outer {
  Inner inner;
};

class MyClass {
public:
  Outer outer;
  Inner& inner; // refers to outer.inner, for convenience

  MyClass() : inner(outer.inner) {}

  void ConstMethod() const {
    inner.Modify();  // oops; compiles
  }
};
```

It further appears to be possible to use this loophole to modify an object declared as `const`, which I believe is undefined behaviour:

```
int main() {
    const MyClass myclass;
    std::cout << myclass.outer.inner.field << "\n";  // prints 0
    myclass.ConstMethod();
    std::cout << myclass.outer.inner.field << "\n";  // prints 1
}
```

This scares me, because it seems like I've just invoked undefined behaviour related to const-correctness in a program that doesn't use `const_cast` or cast away constness using a C-style cast.

So, my questions are:

- Am I correct to say that the above program has undefined behaviour?
- If so, is this a language bug? Is there a line in the above program that arguably *shouldn't* (could reasonably made not to) compile?
- Are there some guidelines that should be followed to avoid this category of undefined behaviour in practice?

Comment: If you turn on warnings, do you get any about this? I actually don't think this is undefined just inadvisable.

Comment: It is based on a simple fact that inside constructor and destructor a `const` object is always seen as a non-const one. Yes, you can use it to work around const-correctness rules without a cast.

Comment: Not an answer but something that can help prevent this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const

Comment: As I noted below, the relevant question is if `myclass.inner` was "first created" as `const`.  It's not `const` in the definition of `MyClass`, so I honestly don't know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Any modifications](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) to a `const` object is undefined behaviour, and the snippet does indeed do that.

The program isn't ill-formed (which would then require a compile error), since at the point of initializing `inner`, cv-qualifiers haven't taken effect yet.

From the compiler's standpoint, to issue a warning would require it to analyze all code paths leading up to `inner.Modify()` and proving that `inner` *must* be referring to a `const` object, which is impossible in the general case.

The best suggestion is likely to not have internal pointers/references, which are evil anyways.

Comment: But `myClass.inner` _isn't_ `const` -- it's merely "treated as `const`" within `MyClass::ConstMethod() const`.

Comment: The key quote from that page (with emphasis added): "When an object is _first created_, the cv-qualifiers used ... determine the constness or volatility of the object ... ."

Comment: Oops, missed that `myclass` is itself declared `const`.  Not sure how to undo the damage I've done, though.  Sorry.

Comment: It's still not completely clear that `myclass.outer` is considered to have been `const` when it was "first created," and that's the relevant question.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen A subobject is obviously part of the object, otherwise you will be able to do whatever you want with a class. Read [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.cv#4) and [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.type.qualifier#1.1) if you are still unconvinced.

Comment: yep, those links seem pretty clear.  `myclass.inner` is non-`const` in the definition of `MyClass` and is non-`const` in the constructor (which allows the non-`const` reference to bind), but it's still "a non-mutable subobject of [a `const`] object" when it is created (quote from your second link).  Thanks for tracking down those links -- I'm convinced!

Comment: PasserBy: "otherwise you will be able to do whatever you want with a class."

This isn't true in general.  The OP is "exploiting" a very specific situation in which the `class` itself provides the requisite access to its own member.  Without the `class` being set up this way, there would be no loophole.  Now, there's plenty of behavior that is ill-advised but _isn't_ undefined, and it wasn't immediately obvious that exploiting the `class`'s setup in this manner fell into the latter bin rather than just the former.  I agree that your links are pretty clear on this point, though.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error in code, remember that const refers to the innermost element of the declarator. Basically the const on ConstMethod makes the reference:

```
Inner& const inner;
```

Of course that does not make any real difference because references cannot be re-bound. Think of doing the same thing with a pointer instead and you would realize that inner could still be modified. If it were:

```
Inner * const inner;
```

you could call inner->Modify().

Comment: I am aware of *why* it compiles - that wasn't the question. The question was whether the code is invoking undefined behaviour, and whether the language rules could be modified to catch this at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

This shouldn't be undefined behavior.  Yes, `myclass.outer` is treated as `const` inside `MyClass::ConstMethod() const`, but it didn't *begin* its existence as `const` and hence it should be safely modifiable through non-`const` references.  Of course, doing so may surprise readers and/or users of your code, so you should try to avoid this.

This is analogous to

```
int x = 5;
int * xPtr = &x;
const int * constXPtr = &x;
```

in which the existence of `constXPtr` doesn't (and shouldn't) prevent one from modifying `x` through `xPtr`.

It's worth noting that such aliasing possibilities prevent a lot of potential compiler optimizations.

Comment: Oops.  The above is useful information in some sense, but I just noticed that the OP declares `myclass` as `const`.  Thus, this does indeed seem like an unfortunate loophole in the type system, creating a `const` object while binding a non-`const` reference to it at the same time.

Comment: It's still not completely clear that `myclass.outer` is considered to have been `const` when it was "first created," and that's the relevant question.